# replicate function for a length-indexed list using GHC.TypeLits and singletons

Tags: list, haskell, dependent-type, singleton-type

I'm trying to write a replicate function for a length-indexed list using the machinery from [GHC.TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html), [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1), and [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10).

The `Vect` type and signature for `replicateVec` are given below:

```
data Vect :: Nat -> Type -> Type where
  VNil  :: Vect 0 a
  VCons :: a -> Vect (n - 1) a -> Vect n a

replicateVec :: forall n a. SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
```

How can you write this `replicateVec` function?

---

I have a version of `replicateVec` that compiles and type checks, but it appears to go into an infinite loop when run.  The code is below.  I have added comments to try to make the laws and proofs I am using a little easier to understand:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}

module VectStuff where

import Data.Constraint ((:-)(Sub), Dict(Dict))
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Singletons.Decide (Decision(Disproved, Proved), Refuted, (:~:)(Refl), (%~))
import Data.Singletons.Prelude (PNum((-)), sing)
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits (SNat, Sing(SNat))
import GHC.TypeLits (CmpNat, KnownNat, Nat)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

data Vect :: Nat -> Type -> Type where
  VNil  :: Vect 0 a
  VCons :: forall n a. a -> Vect (n - 1) a -> Vect n a

deriving instance Show a => Show (Vect n a)

-- This is used to define the two laws below.
axiom :: Dict a
axiom = unsafeCoerce (Dict :: Dict ())

-- | This law says that if we know that @n@ is not 0, then it MUST be
-- greater than 0.
nGT0CmpNatLaw :: (Refuted (n :~: 0)) -> Dict (CmpNat n 0 ~ 'GT)
nGT0CmpNatLaw _ = axiom

-- | This law says that if we know that @n@ is greater than 0, then we know
-- that @n - 1@ is also a 'KnownNat'.
cmpNatGT0KnownNatLaw :: forall n. (CmpNat n 0 ~ 'GT) :- KnownNat (n - 1)
cmpNatGT0KnownNatLaw = Sub axiom

-- | This is a proof that if we have an @n@ that is greater than 0, then
-- we can get an @'SNat' (n - 1)@
sNatMinus1 :: forall n. (CmpNat n 0 ~ 'GT) => SNat n -> SNat (n - 1)
sNatMinus1 SNat =
  case cmpNatGT0KnownNatLaw @n of
    Sub Dict -> SNat

-- | This is basically a combination of the other proofs.  If we have a
-- @SNat n@ and we know that it is not 0, then we can get an @SNat (n -1)@
-- that we know is a 'KnownNat'.
nGT0Proof ::
     forall n.
     Refuted (n :~: 0)
  -> SNat n
  -> (SNat (n - 1), Dict (KnownNat (n - 1)))
nGT0Proof f snat =
  case nGT0CmpNatLaw f of
    Dict ->
      case cmpNatGT0KnownNatLaw @n of
        Sub d -> (sNatMinus1 snat, d)

replicateVec :: forall n a. SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicateVec snat a =
  -- First we check if @snat@ is 0.
  case snat %~ (sing @_ @0) of
    -- If we get a proof that @snat@ is 0, then we just return 'VNil'.
    Proved Refl -> VNil
    -- If we get a proof that @snat@ is not 0, then we use 'nGT0Proof'
    -- to get @n - 1@, and pass that to 'replicateVec' recursively.
    Disproved f ->
      case nGT0Proof f snat of
        (snat', Dict) -> VCons a $ replicateVec snat' a
```

However, for some reason this `replicateVec` function goes into an endless loop when I try to run it:

```
> replicateVec (sing @_ @3) "4"
["4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4",^CInterrupted.
```

Why is this happening?  How can I write the `replicateVec` function correctly?

Comment: `cmpNatGT0KnownNatLaw` is wrong, `KnownNat n` should contain a runtime integer equal to `n`, and you merely give it a `Dict ()`. Singleton subtraction would give you the actual number, but I think using `-` in the `Vec` definition is not a good idea in the first place.

Comment: I tried to add some contraints to my VCons constructor, but I end up with a weird compile error (or a runtime crash) when trying to pattern match on a VCons: https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/6d4769dbd3c429d284b1eb8b9a12fb75

Comment: @AndrásKovács I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.  Isn't `KnownNat n` just a constraint?  I don't understand how it should contain a runtime integer?  Maybe you're talking about how typeclasses end up being passed as dictionaries at runtime?  I don't understand the interaction between that and `Dict`.  Would you be able to expand on your answer a little?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the capacity to explain now. [Here's a working version](http://lpaste.net/364525), maybe I'll write a proper answer later.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Thanks a lot! Is using something like your NatView necessary for this?  I was hoping to do it with just the machinery from GHC.TypeLits and singletons.  Also, this is a terminology question, but would your NatView be referred to as "structural equality"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`axiom :: Dict a` is very unsafe because the runtime representation of a `Dict a` depends on the constraint `a` (which corresponds to a dictionary that is captured by the `Dict` constructor).

A `KnownNat` constraint corresponds to an integer value at runtime, so it is not correct to construct a `Dict` of `KnownNat` using `unsafeCoerce` on a dummy dictionary (in `cmpNatGT0KnownNatLaw`). In particular, this integer is used in `replicateVec` to check whether the integer is `0`.

Type equalities `(~)` are special in that they have no meaningful runtime representation, hence `axiom`-atizing equalities, if they are correct, technically does not lead to bad runtime behavior because the coerced dictionary is never used, but coercing from `Dict ()` to a `Dict (a ~ b)` is certainly not a supported use of `unsafeCoerce`. Coercing between equalities might be more reliable.

To solve `KnownNat` constraints, *constraints* internally associates the type-level operations to their term-level counterparts, see [`magic` in `Data.Constraints.Nat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/src/Data-Constraint-Nat.html) and reconstructs the `KnownNat` dictionary based on implicit knowledge about how GHC represents type classes.

---

Anyway, for an inductive construction like `replicate`, we can avoid `KnownNat`, and use a different singleton type that reflects the inductive nature of `Nat`.

```
data Sing n where
  Z :: Sing 0
  S :: Sing n -> Sing (1 + n)
```

This singleton is actually annoying to use because `(+)` is not injective. (`\x -> (1 + x)` technically is injective, but GHC can't tell that much.) It would be easier with an actually inductively defined `Nat`, but still, with the right set of constraints, we can do some things. For example, singleton reflection (mapping from the type-level `n` to a `Sing n` value):

```
class SingN n where
  singN :: Sing n

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} SingN 0 where
  singN = Z

instance (n ~ (1 + n'), n' ~ (n - 1), SingN n') => SingN n where
  singN = S (singN @n')
```

The list type should be similarly structured:

```
data List n a where
  Nil :: List 0 a
  Cons :: a -> List n a -> List (1 + n) a
```

The reason to set up the type index `n` this way instead of `Sing (n-1) -> Sing n` and `a -> List (n-1) a -> List n a` is to forbid some silly values:

```
oops :: Sing 0
oops = S undefined

ouch :: List 0 ()
ouch = Cons () undefined
```

which would be a problem because functions would actually need to handle those cases which make no sense.

`replicate` turns out to be straightforward to implement because `List` and `Sing` have a lot of structure in common.

```
replicate :: Sing n -> a -> List n a
replicate Z _ = Nil
replicate (S n) a = Cons a (replicate n a)
```

We can now apply `replicate` as follows:

```
replicate (singN @3) "x"
```

- [Compilable gist](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/089c0a0ce7900923716cdbf79fc4fa99)

Comment: I belive the `sing` function at the very end of your post should instead be `singN`.  (I tried to make this edit myself, but StackOverflow yelled at me saying my edit wasn't substantial enough.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!  I've learned a lot from it.  I have come up with a couple different versions of my original code that works now.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/3f187c2cce0d2216febd44dea25d41e6) is a version using the `magic` trick you've described.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/05b50263638edacdc8b0b727bbd7cc39) is a version with the formulation of `Vect` you suggest.  I only need the `axiom` trick for this.

Comment: I've been playing around with this a little more.  I came up with [some code](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/bbe57f0f3dc50ed0d74ee5188cf72f08) that does basically what you suggested, but using the functionality from singletons.  It ends up being much longer than your code!

Comment: And just for completion, [here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/0d47b2288d5681c9742de604f80b760f) is a version that uses `magic`  (instead of Peano numbers), but doesn't use anything from singletons.

Comment: It might be slightly safer to create `axiom` by coercing a `Dict (a ~ a)` instead of `Dict ()`.

Comment: @illabout, it's more common to use `Data.Type.Equality.:~:` than `Dict` for equalities. It's also likely to be more efficient, but I don't have time now to explain why.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer.  I added another version [here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/58d1edebdae0035f8d940701b9fceb15#file-vec-proofs-using-refl-instead-of-dict-hs-L36-L37) that uses `Refl` for equality rather than `Dict`.

Comment: @dfeuer I would be interested in why it is more efficient to use `Refl` rather than `Dict`.  I'm guessing because `Dict` needs to carry around the constraint it is holding.  Under the hood, it is like `Dict` is a data constructor with a single parameter (unlike `Refl`, which is a data construcotr with no parameters).  Is this on the right track?

Comment: @illabout, yes, that's it. Internally, `~` is boxed, while the equalities expressed by GADT constructors are unboxed--internally they use `~n#` constraints, which are zero-width.