# How to use the dependent pair type Sigma from the singletons library?

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type, singleton-type

How can the dependent pair type [Sigma](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2018-04-14/singletons-2.4.1/Data-Singletons-Sigma.html#t:Sigma) from the [singletons](https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2018-04-14/package/singletons-2.4.1) library be used?

Let's assume the following type-indexed list and replicate function exist:

```
data Vect :: Nat -> Type -> Type where
  VNil :: Vect 0 a
  VCons :: a -> Vect n a -> Vect (n + 1) a

replicateVec :: forall n a. Sing n -> a -> Vect n a
```

(You can find a couple different implementations of `replicateVec` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709113/replicate-function-for-a-length-indexed-list-using-ghc-typelits-and-singletons)).

I'd like to create a function `replicateVecSigma` that returns a `Vect` in a dependent pair.  Ideally it would be like the following:

```
replicateVecSigma :: Natural -> Sigma Nat (\n -> Vect n String)
```

How can `Sigma` be used to write this function?  And how can the type of the function be written?

---

Actually, I am able to implement `replicateVecSigma` as follows but it doesn't seem very clean:

```
data Foo a b (m :: TyFun Nat Type)

type instance Apply (Foo a b) (n :: Nat) = a n b

replicateVecSigma :: Natural -> Sigma Nat (Foo Vect String)
replicateVecSigma i =
  case toSing i of
    SomeSing snat -> snat :&: replicateVec snat "hello"
```

It seems unfortunate that I have to declare this `Foo` type and `Apply` instance just to use `Sigma`.  Does the `singletons` library provide any way to make working with `Sigma` easier?

You can find my full code [here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/3540e1313dd17b16a703508624a6aee0).

---

For completeness, here is the definition of `Sigma`:

```
data Sigma (s :: Type) :: (s ~> Type) -> Type where
  (:&:) :: forall s t fst. Sing (fst :: s) -> t @@ fst -> Sigma s t
```

Here is [`~>`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2018-04-14/singletons-2.4.1/Data-Singletons.html#t:-126--62-):

```
type a ~> b = TyFun a b -> *

data TyFun :: * -> * -> *

instance (SingKind k1, SingKind k2) => SingKind (k1 ~> k2)

type instance Demote (k1 ~> k2) = Demote k1 -> Demote k2

class SingKind k where
  type family Demote k :: * = r | r -> k
  fromSing :: forall (a :: k). Sing a -> Demote k
  toSing :: Demote k -> SomeSing k
```

Here is [`@@`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2018-04-14/singletons-2.4.1/Data-Singletons.html#t:-64--64-):

```
type a @@ b = Apply a b

type family Apply (f :: k1 ~> k2) (x :: k1) :: k2
```

`singletons` defines a bunch of instances for `Apply`.

How do [`TyFun`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2018-04-14/singletons-2.4.1/Data-Singletons.html#t:TyFun) and [`Apply`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2018-04-14/singletons-2.4.1/Data-Singletons.html#t:Apply) work?

---

Here are the three questions from above:

1. How can I use `Sigma` to write a function like `replicateVecSigma :: Natural -> Sigma Nat (\n -> Vect n String)`?
2. I am able to write `replicateVecSigma` using the `Foo` type above, but it seems like too much extra work.  Is there an easier way?
3. How do `TyFun` and `Apply` work?

Comment: All this complicated stuff is a result of `singletons`'s _defunctionalisation_-based encoding of type functions. The author of `singletons` has written about it [on his blog](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/defunctionalization-for-the-win/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, we want to compute the type-level lambda

```
\n -> Vect n String
```

Unfortunately, we do not have lambdas at the type level. At most, we can define type families, as the OP did. However, we can rewrite the lambda in pointfree style:

```
\n -> flip Vect String n    -- pseudocode
flip Vect String
```

and we can turn this idea into an actual type, using the `singletons` type-level `Flip` type function. Here, we want to partially apply `Flip` with two arguments (it takes three, in a saturated call), so we use the "defunctionalized" `FlipSym2` variant instead.

This compiles:

```
replicateVecSigma :: Natural -> Sigma Nat (FlipSym2 (TyCon Vect) String)
replicateVecSigma i =
  case toSing i of
    SomeSing snat -> snat :&: replicateVec snat "hello"
```

If we had the `n` argument in the last position from the beginning, we could have avoided the `Flip`.

```
data Vect2 :: Type -> Nat -> Type where
  VNil2 :: Vect2 a 0
  VCons2 :: a -> Vect2 a n -> Vect2 a (n + 1)

replicateVec2 :: forall n a. Sing n -> a -> Vect2 a n
replicateVec2 = undefined

replicateVecSigma2 :: Natural -> Sigma Nat (TyCon (Vect2 String))
replicateVecSigma2 i =
  case toSing i of
    SomeSing snat -> snat :&: replicateVec2 snat "hello"
```

( `TyCon Vect2 @@ String` also works here, using the explicit application `@@` at the defunctionalized level, instead of the actuall type applciation.)

Very roughly put, you can think of the defunctionalized variants like `FlipSym0, FlipSym1, FlipSym2` as basic tags (not functions!), with no intrinsic meaning, except for the fact that `Apply` lets you work with them *pretending* they were functions. In this way we can work with non-functions ("tags") as if they were functions. This is needed since, in Haskell, we do not have functions at the type level, so we have to work with these "pretend" versions.

The approach is general, but it does require more work from the programmer than one would like.

I am not aware of any Template Haskell utility that can automatically turn type-level lambdas into pointfree form, and then defunctionalize them. That would be quite useful.

Comment: I think you've used `TyCon` when you need to use `TyCon2` a few times?

Comment: @HTNW I also thought that, but my code compiled anyway. Now I see that `TyCon` is a `data family` which automatically handles the arity. Its doc on github states "Workhorse for the 'TyCon1', etc., types. This can be used directly in place of any of the @TyConN@ types, but it will work only with /monomorphic/ types. When GHC#14645 is fixed, this should fully supersede the @TyConN@ types."

Answer (score 4):

*Defunctionalization* is a general way to work around the lack of first-class functions (in fact, it was originally discovered as a compilation technique to get rid of those), encoding them as *symbols* that get interpreted by a single first-order `Apply` function.

For example, your `Foo a b` is a symbol that encodes the function `\n -> a n b`.

---

Another way of obtaining an equivalent symbol is to follow the intuition that `(\n -> a n b) = flip a b`.

Note that type constructors like `Vec` are not themselves symbols that can be passed to `Apply`, but must be wrapped in "symbol constructors": `TyCon2 Vec` is the symbol for `\n -> \b -> Vec n b`.

*singletons* has a symbol for `flip`, `FlipSym0` (symbols can stand for higher-order functions by taking other symbols as arguments).

```
Foo a b = Apply (Apply FlipSym0 (TyCon2 a)) b
```

Note that partial applications reduce to other symbols:

```
        = Apply (FlipSym1 (TyCon2 a)) b
        = FlipSym2 (TyCon2 a) b
```

---

The `TyFun` type is a way to give types to defunctionalized symbols. The main benefit I see is type inference; without it, type families might get stuck in confusing ways.

See also this blogpost by Richard Eisenberg on defunctionalization for Haskell types: https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/defunctionalization-for-the-win/