# When to use existential type vs. dependent pair in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, singleton, dependent-type, existential-type, type-level-computation

When would one want to use a specialized existential type vs. a dependent pair (also called a dependent sum or sigma type)?

Here is an example.

The following is a length-indexed list and dependently-typed replicate function.  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709113/replicate-function-for-a-length-indexed-list-using-ghc-typelits-and-singletons) for how to implement `replicateVect`.  The following is using the [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1) library:

```
data Vect :: Type -> Nat -> Type where
  VNil :: Vect a 0
  VCons :: a -> Vect a n -> Vect a (n + 1)

replicateVect :: forall n a. SNat n -> a -> Vect a n
```

There are (at least) two possible ways to create a replicate function that takes a normal [`Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html), instead of a singleton [`SNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1/docs/Data-Singletons-TypeLits.html#t:SNat).

One way is to create a specialized existential type for `Vect`.  I call this `SomeVect`, following the conventions of `singletons`:

```
data SomeVect :: Type -> Type where
  SomeVect :: forall a n. Vect a n -> SomeVect a

replicateExistentialVect :: forall a. Natural -> a -> SomeVect a
replicateExistentialVect nat a =
  case toSing nat of
    SomeSing sNat -> SomeVect $ replicateVect sNat a
```

Another way is to use a dependent pair.  This uses the [`Sigma`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1/docs/Data-Singletons-Sigma.html) type from `singletons`:

```
replicateSigmaVect :: forall n a. Natural -> a -> Sigma Nat (TyCon (Vect a))
replicateSigmaVect nat a =
  case toSing nat of
    SomeSing sNat -> sNat :&: replicateVect sNat a
```

These functions looks very similar.  Using `replicateExistentialVect` and `replicteSigmaVect` is also very similar:

```
testReplicateExistentialVect :: IO ()
testReplicateExistentialVect =
  case replicateExistentialVect 3 "hello" of
    SomeVect vect -> print vect

testReplicateSigmaVect :: IO ()
testReplicateSigmaVect =
  case replicateSigmaVect 3 "hello" of
    _ :&: vect -> print vect
```

The full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/91f6a36f3451e1026bdd01e83c3ba5fb).

---

This brings me to my questions.

1. When should I use a specialized existential type (like `SomeVect`) vs. a dependent pair (like `Sigma`)?
2. Are there any functions that can **only** be written with one or the other?
3. Are there any functions that are significantly easier to write with one or the other?

Comment: I guess another possibility would be a generalized existential type, as explained in section 3.3 of [Stitch: The Sound Type-Indexed Type Checker](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2018/stitch/stitch.pdf).  I implemented replicate for a generalized existential type [here](https://gist.github.com/cdepillabout/91f6a36f3451e1026bdd01e83c3ba5fb#file-existential-vs-sigma-hs-L97-L108).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. When should I use a specialized existential type (like `SomeVect`) vs. a dependent pair (like `Sigma`)?

This question is somewhat tricky to answer, because:

1. `Sigma` is itself a form of specialized existential type.
2. There are infinitely many ways to create specialized existential types—`SomeVect` and `Sigma` are just two examples of the phenomenon.

Nevertheless, it does feel as if `Sigma` is subtly different from other ways of encoding existential types in GHC. Let's try and identify what exactly makes it different.

First, let's write out the definition of `Sigma`, in its full glory:

```
    data Sigma (s :: Type) :: (s ~> Type) -> Type where
      (:&:) :: forall s (t :: s ~> Type) (x :: s).
               Sing x -> Apply t x -> Sigma s t
```

And for comparison, I'll also define a "typical" existential type:

```
    data Ex :: (s -> Type) -> Type where
      MkEx :: forall s (t :: s -> Type) (x :: s).
              t x -> Ex t
```

Let's go over the differences between the two:

1. `Sigma s t` has two type arguments, whereas `Ex t` only has one. This isn't a terribly significant difference, and in fact, you could write `Sigma` using only one argument:

   ```
   data Sigma :: (s ~> Type) -> Type where
     (:&:) :: forall s (t :: s ~> Type) (x :: s).
              Sing x -> Apply t x -> Sigma t
   ```

   Or `Ex` using two arguments:

   ```
   data Ex (s :: Type) :: (s -> Type) -> Type where
     MkEx :: forall s (t :: s -> Type) (x :: s).
             t x -> Ex s t
   ```

   The only reason why I opted to use two arguments in `Sigma` is to more closely match the presentation of dependent pairs in other languages, such as in [Idris's `DPair`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/prelude_doc/docs/Builtins.html#Builtins.DPair). It also perhaps makes the analogy between `Sigma s t` and `∃ (x ∈ s). t(x)` clearer.
2. Much more importantly, the kind of `Sigma`'s last argument, `s ~> Type`, is different from the kind of `Ex`'s argument, `s -> Type`. In particular, the difference is between the [`(~>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:-126--62-) and `(->)` kinds. The latter, `(->)` is the familiar function arrow, whereas the former, `(~>)`, is the kind of defunctionalization symbols in `singletons`.

   What are defunctionalization symbols, and why do they need their own kind? They're explained in section 4.3 of the paper [*Promoting Functions to Type Families in Haskell*](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/%7Erae/papers/2014/promotion/promotion.pdf), but I'll try to give a condensed version here. Essentially, we want to be able to write type families like:

   ```
   type family Positive (n :: Nat) :: Type where
     Positive Z     = Void
     Positive (S _) = ()
   ```

   And be able to use the type `Sigma Nat Positive`. But this won't work, since you can't partially apply a type family like `Positive`. Luckily, the defunctionalization trick lets us work around this issue. Using the following definitions:

   ```
   data TyFun :: Type -> Type -> Type

   type a ~> b = TyFun a b -> Type
   infixr 0 ~>

   type family Apply (f :: k1 ~> k2) (x :: k1) :: k2
   ```

   We can define a *defunctionalization symbol* for `Positive` that lets us partially apply it:

   ```
   data PositiveSym0 :: Nat ~> Type
   type instance Apply PositiveSym0 n = Positive n
   ```

   Now, in the type `Sigma Nat PositiveSym0`, the second field is of type `Apply PositiveSym0 x`, or just `Positive x`. Thus, `(~>)` is in some sense more general than `(->)`, since it lets us use *more* types than `(->)` would.

   (If it helps, one can think of `(~>)` as the kind of *unmatchable* functions, as described in Section 4.2.4 of [Richard Eisenberg's thesis](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2016/thesis/eisenberg-thesis.pdf), whereas `(->)` is the kind of *matchable* functions.)
3. While the `MkEx` constructor only has one field, the `(:&:)` constructor has an additional field (of type `Sing x`). There are two reasons for this. One is that storing this extra field is, by definition, part of what makes `Sigma` a dependent pair, and this allows us to retrieve it by way of the [`projSigma1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1/docs/Data-Singletons-Sigma.html#v:projSigma1) function. Another reason is that if you took out the `Sing x` field:

   ```
   data Sigma (s :: Type) :: (s ~> Type) -> Type where
     (:&:) :: forall s (t :: s ~> Type) (x :: s).
              Apply t x -> Sigma s t
   ```

   Then this definition would require `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, as the `x` type variable is ambiguous. This might be burdensome, so having an explicit `Sing x` field avoids this.

---

Now that I've finished my long-winded explanation, let me try to actually answer your questions:

> 1. When should I use a specialized existential type (like `SomeVect`) vs. a dependent pair (like `Sigma`)?

I think this is ultimately a matter of personal taste. `Sigma` is nice because it's pretty darn general, but you may find that defining a specialized existential type makes your code easier to understand. (But also see the caveats below.)

> 2. Are there any functions that can only be written with one or the other?

I suppose my earlier `Sigma Nat PositiveSym0` example would count as something you couldn't do with `Ex`, since it requires exploiting the `(~>)` kind. On the other hand, you could just as well define:

```
data SomePositiveNat :: Type where
  SPN :: Sing (n :: Nat) -> Positive n -> SomePositiveNat
```

So you'd don't technically need `(~>)` to do this.

Additionally, I don't know of a way to write a `projSigma1` equivalent for `Ex`, since it doesn't store enough information in order to be able to write this.

On the other hand, `Sigma s t` requires that there be a `Sing` instance for the kind `s`, so if there isn't one, `Sigma` is probably not going to work.

> 3. Are there any functions that are significantly easier to write with one or the other?

You'll have an easier time using `Sigma` when you have a pressing need to use something with a `(~>)` kind, since that is where it shines. If your type can get away with just a `(->)` kind, it might be more convenient to use a "typical" existential type like `Ex`, because otherwise you have to introduce noise in the form of [`TyCon`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:TyCon) to lift something of kind `s -> Type` to `s ~> Type`.

Also, you might find `Sigma` easier to work with if being able to retrieve the field of type `Sing x` conveniently is important.

Comment: A specialized existential can of course offer two fields as well. `data SomeVec a where SV :: SNat n -> Vec n a -> SomeVec a`.